# How to get the id of the current user when logging web api requests via middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, middleware

I have the following `Invoke` function within a middleware to log the web api requests. It is based on [this example](https://salslab.com/a/safely-logging-api-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core), and it works fine. However, I also want to save the `username` of the current user who is sending the request.

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IApiLogService apiLogService)
 {
     try
     {
         _apiLogService = apiLogService;

         var request = httpContext.Request;
         if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))
         {
             var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
             var requestTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
             var requestBodyContent = await ReadRequestBody(request);
             var originalBodyStream = httpContext.Response.Body;

             await SafeLog(requestTime,
                   stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                   200,//response.StatusCode,
                   request.Method,
                   request.Path,
                   request.QueryString.ToString(),
                   requestBodyContent
                   );           
         }
         else
         {
             await _next(httpContext);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         await _next(httpContext);
     }
 }
```

However, the `User` property of `httpContext` seems to missing user information. Below I share its content. I wonder how I can get the id of the user who is sending the request. I am not using windows authentication. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: At a guess, your middleware is running before the authentication middleware. Please can you show how you configured both of these?

Comment: @John thanks a lot! You are right :) First time I am using a middleware. I am happy that the solution is that easy!

Answer (score 2):

The key point to explain why this happens

> the User property of httpContext seems to missing user information

Is the order of middleware in the Configure method of the Startup class.
The ASP.NET Core request pipeline processing works by running middleware components as per the sequence they are placed in the Configure method of the Startup class.

so you needs to move  `app.UseAuthentication();` to be before you add your custom middleware  to pipline `app.UseYourMiddleware();` in the Configure method of the Startup class.